# View frame height decrease and black bar appear

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using ECSlidingMenu with my project and I need to change rootview manually so I use this code

```
UINavigationController *transferView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Transfer"];

        [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
            CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController = transferView;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
            [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
        }];
```

after resetTopView , I got black weird bar as you see in image.

If I run the code (Change RootView Again) black bar will grow higher.

Does anyone undergo this issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this code in the current `topViewController`? Is the frame being set?

Comment: Yes, following code is set in My FirstViewController and I want to change view from FirstView -> TransferViewController.

Comment: So is the frame set? And does it animate back? Debug to check the frame and if anything else is changing the frame.

Comment: I already check it, frame size was changed after resetTopView.
But I didn't 'Debug' in ECSlingViewController code.

Comment: Finally, I can fix it. after search similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change code to be like this.

```
ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = self.slidingViewController;

[slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
    CGRect frame = slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
    slidingViewController.topViewController = transferView;
    slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
    [slidingViewController resetTopView];
}];
```

this solve problem. I have no idea why... but it's worked.

Thank you :--> [Switching views with ECSliding without navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277606/switching-views-with-ecsliding-without-navigation-menu?rq=1)